# Regular expression to validate time

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the Regular Expression 
`"(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][1-4]):[0-5]?[0-9]\s?(?:AM|am|PM|pm)?"`  to validate time.

```
var Regexp = new RegExp("(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][1-4]):[0-5]?[0-9]\s?(?:AM|am|PM|pm)?");
if (Regexp.test(starttime)) {
    var match = Regexp.exec(starttime);
    if (match) {
        s = match[0];
    }
}
```

My input is `"7:00 AM"`. But my `match[0]` returns only `"7.00"` . This does not return `AM` or `PM` . There also seems to be only one group. How do I get **AM/PM** with the group?

Comment: Why not simply parse it into some kind of date/time object and use that?

Comment: "simply parse"  good one

Comment: None of the answers give me 7.00 AM

Comment: @George: do you mean 7:00 AM?  My answer gives you this, as you'll see from my test cases in the answer

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you're using a string to define the regular expression, and using `\s` within that string. `\` in strings is an escape character, so the regex doesn't see the `\s`, it just sees `s` (because `"\s" === "s"`, the escape doesn't actually do anything). You'd need `\\s` instead.

But far better to use literal syntax:

```
var rex = /(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][1-4]):[0-5]?[0-9]\s?(?:AM|am|PM|pm)?/;
```

*(I also changed the name, `Regexp` is just too close to `RegExp`.)*

**Live Example:**

```js
var starttime = "7:00 AM";
var rex = /(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][1-4]):[0-5]?[0-9]\s?(?:AM|am|PM|pm)?/;
if (rex.test(starttime)) {
  var match = rex.exec(starttime);
  if (match) {
    snippet.log(match[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: `20` hours won't get matched due to `[1-4]` (in OP's regex neither, must be a typo I guess): should be `[0-4]`. Also, it can be slightly shortened: `/(?:[01]?\d|2[0-4]):[0-5]?\d\s?(?:[ap]m)?/i`.

Comment: @sp00m: I didn't optimize or change the scope of the regex, just explained why it wasn't matching the provided input. Presumably the OP is intentionally supporting only 12-hour am/pm values (e.g., 8 PM) rather than 24-hour values (20 hours).

Comment: what if my input is 12/22/2015 07:00:17.965 AM ?

Comment: @George: Then you'll have to adjust the regular expression to deal with that, because currently it doesn't allow for either seconds or fractional seconds. Questions on Stack Overflow aren't supposed to be moving targets.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:)` defines a non-capturing group. Remove the `?:` if you want capturing groups.

---

As there is some confusion this is a more complete answer:

If you want `s` to contain `"7:00 AM"` you can either use the literal syntax `//` or escape the `\s` with another slash (`\\s`). Note that `match[0]` is not a group but the full match.

If you want **first group - the time** and **second one - am/pm** - [this slight modification will do](https://regex101.com/r/jM3nY0/1):

```
((?:[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][1-4]):[0-5]?[0-9])\s?(AM|am|PM|pm)?
```

Comment: Also, backslash should be escaped, `\\s`, or use regex literal

Comment: removed (?:) to get  "([0-1]?[0-9]|[2][1-4]):[0-5]?[0-9]\\s?(?:AM|am|PM|pm)?" . still i am not getting AM/PM

Comment: @George, there is another problem too then. One sec.

Comment: I want output as 7.00 AM in group

Comment: @George, use the literal syntax `/(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][1-4]):[0-5]?[0-9]\s?(AM|am|PM|pm)?/` instead of `new RegExp("(?:[0-1]?[0-9]|[2][1-4]):[0-5]?[0-9]\s?(?:AM|am|PM|pm)?")`

Comment: `[0]` isn't a capture group, it's the full match. The first capture group (if there were any) would be `[1]`.

Comment: @sp00m: yeah, sorry. Overlooked the implementation part, too used to these questions being javascript with regex literals. I will remove my comment to keep this clean

Answer (score 0):

You have an escape sequence issue, where `\s` becomes `s` in your regex.

However, even after you use the preferred [literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to fix that issue, you still have to consider a couple of edge cases.  24:00 should not be a time, and 20:00 should be, so change your `[1-4]` to `[0-3]`.  Secondly, `23:00 AM` makes no sense nor does `13:00 PM`.  To fix this, you should split your regex into two pieces so that you match either a 12 hour time, or a 24 hour time.  Thirdly, the time `7:0 PM` also matches, because you have a `?` after your first minutes digit.  There should always be two minutes digits.

As always with regex, make test cases!  This will help you see where your regex is going wrong (or not going wrong).

Working regex: (Thanks to TJ Crowder for the awesome snippet tool)

```js
var tests = ["20:00", "24:00", "13:00 PM", "7:0 AM", "7:00 AM"];

var regex12hrTime = /((0?[0-9])|(1[0-2])):[0-5][0-9]\s?(AM|am|PM|pm)/;
var regex24hrTime = /([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/;

for (var idx=0; idx<tests.length; idx++) {
  var test = tests[idx];
  if (regex12hrTime.test(test)) {
    snippet.log(test + " matches with " +
                regex12hrTime.exec(test)[0]);
  } else if (regex24hrTime.test(test)) {
    snippet.log(test + " matches with " +
                regex24hrTime.exec(test)[0]);
  } else {
    snippet.log(test + " does not match");
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```